# How to register a helper function in Handlebars in Nest application without using express-handlebars module?

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, nestjs, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

In my Nest application I am using [`handlebars`](https://handlebarsjs.com/) for generating HTML.

I setup hbs by following official way given at https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc which involves

`npm install --save hbs`

In `main.ts`

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(
    AppModule,
  );

  app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));
  app.setBaseViewsDir(join(__dirname, '..', 'views'));
  app.setViewEngine('hbs');

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

I want to format datetime stamp in my desired format so I need to register custom helper functions for Handlebars.

[Official example](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/15-mvc) does not cover way to register helper functions.

I found a way which usage [`express-handlebars`](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars) module which I want to avoid at https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/745

How can I register a helper function in Handlebars in Nest application without using  express-handlebars module?